# Diffing two versions in Hg

Tags: eclipse, version-control, mercurial, diff, dvcs

I am trying to view the differences between two versions of a project. The way I initially thought to do it:

1. Create new repository
2. Commit first version to repository
3. Overwrite first version with second version, commit to repository
4. `hg diff` the two versions

This did not work, because when the second version overwrote the first version Mercurial assumed every single file was changed. In reality only a few files are changed, and I want to see what specifically was changed in each file.

WinDiff gives me a list of the files that were changed but that is it, so I would really like to use Hg to get the specifics.

**EDIT:** I am using Eclipse. What I specifically am doing is creating a new Java project, using Eclipse's import feature to import the source files I want, and then commit that project to my repository. I then use import again to import version 2 into the same project so that the files from the first are overwritten. I am left with files that are named the same but that are version 2 files. I then commit the new files to the repository.

My Mercurial version is 1.8.3. Doing the steps above gives me just one changeset.

Also, when creating the diff is there a way to specify to only diff Java files, not text or properties, etc.?

Comment: Mercurial should not add a file to a changeset if it did not change. Are you sure *nothing* changed? Could the files have a different text encoding?

Comment: The files have the same encoding. I think the problem is that once I have the first version committed, I am overwriting the files with the files from the second version so Mercurial thinks the files are brand-new and thus different. I am not sure what the better way to do this is, though

Comment: No, that's not how Mercurial works. It may use things like the timestamp to optimize the finding of which files to analyze, but it compares contents. To test this you can create a new repository, add a file and commit it, then change the file and save it, then change it back (but don't use undo or similar) and save it again, this will make the file appear to have a new timestamp, but if you ask Mercurial to give you the current status, or to commit, the file will not be included. There must be something else happening here.

Comment: A good way to find out what happened is by asking it to diff and looking at the result, in particular one or more of the files you think shouldn't have changed. Do you see any changes for that file, if so, what kind of changes?

Comment: The changes are all basically "fileX-2.1 deleted, fileX-2.2 created"

Comment: How did you "overwrite" the contents? And did you change the name of files? ie. from "fileX-2.1" to "fileX-2.2" ?

Comment: I created a new project and imported the 2.1 source files to it. After committing those to the repository, I imported version 2.2 to the same project. The file names all remained the same, so the 2.2 files overwrote the 2.1 files, I believe.

Comment: I am using Eclipse, so I created a new Java project and then used the import feature. Selected the files I wanted and they were imported to the Java project

Comment: Perhaps Eclipse deleted the old files, and then asked Mercurial to delete those, then it added new files? This would lead to a changeset that both deleted file X and added a new file X, which would thus be considered different, even though they have the same name and possibly the same or similar content. What I would do would be this: 1. Delete the files and folders in the working directory, 2. Copy in the new files and folders, 3. Execute a `hg addremove` followed by a 4. `hg commit`, this would not create that situation. Assuming that *is* the situation of course :)

Comment: ``hg addremove`` did the trick! If you want to write it as an answer I can accept it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I can do that but only if you edit your question so that it contains information about how you imported the second version, ie. using Eclipse. Otherwise future visitors will have to read this entire comment thread (which I'm inclined to delete if all edits comes into place) to figure out how I could guess that that was the problem :)

Comment: Follow-up question, how many changesets did you end up with? When trying to reproduce the problem with just Mercurial it appears that if you instruct Mercurial to remove/forget a file, and then subsequently ask it to add a new file with the same name, it does not create this problem. Also, which version of Mercurial are you using? Perhaps this was a problem with an old version.

Comment: Edited my original question. I didn't try to do it with just mercurial, perhaps I should have done that instead of going through Eclipse!

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure is sound, just remember to use `hg addremove` like Lasse pointed out in the comments. So the full procedure is:

1. Create new repository
2. Import first version to repository
3. Run `hg add` and `hg commit`
4. Delete all files except `.hg`
5. Import second version to repository
6. Run `hg addremove` and `hg commit`
7. `hg diff` the two versions

The `hg addremove` step will even detect files that have been renamed between the two versions. You also write:

> Also, when creating the diff is there a way to specify to only diff java files, not text or properties, etc.?

Yes, you can use the `--include` flag for this:

```
$ hg diff -I '**.java'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it why your can't directly use Mercurial on the original repository of your project.

To see what are the changes to Java files between REV1 and REV2 of your project:

```
hg diff -r REV1 -r REV2 -I **.java
```

Answer (score 0):

To diff two versions of a file in eclipse:

1. Right click on the file and go to Team > Show History
2. The History view should open and show you all the committed versions of the file
3. Double click on the version you want to diff the head with.